# How to get rid of firefox warning message while submitting a DynamicForm in SmartClient?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, smartclient, dynamicform

I have this simple hidden form whose purpose is to redirect the response to a new window on a button click. It works perfect in Internet Explorer 9 and chrome but gives me a warning message in **firefox 11** when **popup block** is on.

**Error Message**

> Form was unable to be submitted. The most likely cause for this is an invalid value in an upload field.

while I am no where trying to upload any files.

**DynamicForm code**

```
dojo.provide("amk.geo.DomainCore.forms.SearchForm");

amk.geo.DomainCore.forms.SearchForm = function() {

    /**
     * Resource bundle.
     * @type Object
     */
    this.bundle = amk.geo.tools.bundles.Application;

    this.formID = null;

    this.controller = null;

    this.resBundle = amk.geo.app.framework.controller.AppController.getResourceBundle("amk.geo.DomainCore.Resources");

    this.initWidget = function() {
            this.Super("initWidget", arguments);
            this.formID = "SearchForm";
            var params = [        
                {type: "hidden", name: "EMAIL_ID" },
                {type: "hidden", name: "PORTAL_PSSWD"},
                {type: "hidden", name: "PROJECT_ID"},
                {type: "hidden", name: "fsquery"},
                {type: "hidden", name: "PRODUCT_VER"},
                {type: "hidden", name: "PRODUCT_NAME"},
                {type: "hidden", name: "ORIGIN"}             
            ];
            this.setItems(params);
            this.action = "https://xxxx.com/default.asp";
            this.method = "POST";
            this.target = "_blank";
            this.canSubmit = true;

    };

    this.onLoad = function(){
        this.submit();
    }
}
// define class
isc.ClassFactory.definePackageClass(
    "amk.geo.DomainCore.forms.SearchForm",    // class name
    isc.DynamicForm     // superclass
);
```

How can I get rid of this warning message? (If I add an exception to the popup blocker, it redirects without any warning message)

[image: *Warning message in Firefox]

Please help. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution to my problem by adding the below lines after `onLoad` function

```
// Override DynamicForm formSubmitFailed function to disable warning alert in Firefox v11 when popups are blocked
this.formSubmitFailed = function(){}
```

You can even check [SmartClient](http://www.smartclient.com/docs/8.2/a/b/c/go.html#attr..DynamicForm.formSubmitFailedWarning) document for more information.